# Iterator that returns each Nth value

Tags: rust

I have an iterator `iter`; is it possible to convert it into an iterator that iterates over each Nth element? Something like `iter.skip_each(n - 1)`?

Comment: There's a `step` iterator in `itertools`: https://bluss.github.io/rust-itertools/doc/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.step

Comment: Nice, though I hoped for something from standard library. Setting in which I use Rust currently makes it... inconvenient to use external crates.

Comment: You'll have a really bad time then. Much work has been invested to make using third party crates simple, and so everyone works under the assumption that adding a dependency is a no brainer. This is not just a cultural thing, it's actively used to justify omitting things from the standard library. I have no idea what your circumstances are but you should try hard to fix that.

Comment: There's a pile of hard-to-fix reasons that one can't easily use external crates, both technical and otherwise. For instance, one might be on a locked-down corporate network (or an otherwise unreliable/slow connection), or have code review requirements for external code (e.g. for licensing). There is [ongoing work in cargo itself](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/pull/2361) to give people more tools for the first case.

Comment: In my case it is that I don't use cargo, as it doesn't really support cross-compilation. Rust advertises as a system programming language, and that is what I use it for right now. Every additional crate I need to download, provide all dependencies for and compile on my own, typically adding a few changes to support my system's API.

Comment: Hm, could you expand? In my experience cargo is one of the nicest cross-compilation experiences I've ever had, as it's just `cargo build --target ...`, and (if you're using `std`/`core`) doubly so with [the new `rustup`](https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/beta-testing-rustup-rs/3316) that makes [installing the standard library for new targets](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rustup.rs/blob/master/README.md#cross-compilation) quite easy. It definitely gets much more annoying with crates with C dependencies, but pure Rust things like `itertools` should slot in seemlessly.

Comment: @huon - yes, you are right. It is a lot more complicated that just "lack of cross-compilation support", I shouldn't have phrased it this way. I am plugging Rust into an older project, that is written mostly in C and it is either impossible or very hard to incorporate cargo in that.

Comment: @anula, ah, makes sense. FWIW, Rust aims to be good at being integrated into older codebases and different languages, so if there's some particular pain points that make cargo not work (beyond just the difficulties of retrofitting new tools into existing infrastructure/build system), be sure to ask/provide feedback on https://users.rust-lang.org/ (or feel free ask here, if it's a question that fits SO). :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As of Rust 1.26, there is the [`Iterator::step_by`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.step_by) method in the standard library:

> Basic usage:
>
> ```
> let a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
> let mut iter = a.iter().step_by(2);
>
> assert_eq!(iter.next(), Some(&0));
> assert_eq!(iter.next(), Some(&2));
> assert_eq!(iter.next(), Some(&4));
> assert_eq!(iter.next(), None);
> ```

Answer (score 7):

As [Dogbert said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36798026/rust-iterator-that-returns-each-n-th-value#comment61170289_36798026), use [itertools' `step`](https://bluss.github.io/rust-itertools/doc/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.step).

You are going to be in a world of hurt if you can't use external crates. The Rust ecosystem strongly encourages everything to be pushed to crates. Maybe you should just clone the repository locally and use it that way if you can.

Otherwise, write it yourself:

```
use std::iter::Fuse;

struct Nth<I> {
    n: usize,
    iter: Fuse<I>,
}

impl<I> Iterator for Nth<I>
    where I: Iterator
{
    type Item = I::Item;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        let mut nth = None;

        for _ in 0..self.n {
            nth = self.iter.next();
        }

        nth
    }
}

trait EveryNth: Iterator + Sized {
    fn every_nth(self, n: usize) -> Nth<Self> {
        Nth { n: n, iter: self.fuse() }
    }
}

impl<I> EveryNth for I where I: Iterator {}

fn main() {
    let x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

    for v in x.iter().every_nth(1) { println!("{}", v) }
    println!("---");
    for v in x.iter().every_nth(2) { println!("{}", v) }
    println!("---");
    for v in x.iter().every_nth(3) { println!("{}", v) }
    println!("---");
    for v in x.iter().every_nth(4) { println!("{}", v) }
    println!("---");
    for v in x.iter().every_nth(5) { println!("{}", v) }
    println!("---");
    for v in x.iter().every_nth(6) { println!("{}", v) }
}
```

Note this is different behavior from itertools. You didn't specify where in the cycle of N the iterator picks from, so I chose the one that was easiest to code.

Comment: That is a pretty nice solution. Since there is nothing in standard library, I guess there is no other way than to implement it if I don't want external crates. I am not sure what you mean by "You didn't specify where in the cycle of N the iterator picks from" but I could just use `x.iter().skip(3).every_nth(5)` if I wanted to shift the window a bit.